# \datavisualization and csv data

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-datavisualization

I'm quite new using tikz and pgf. I use Texmaker.

I get this error: `` PGF Math Error: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit got an ill-formatted floating point number `'. The unreadable part was near '' ``

when I try to run the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{datavisualization}

\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/.cd,
read comma as period,
set thousands separator={}}
\pgfplotstableset{col sep = &}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.6]
\datavisualization[scientific axes, visualize as scatter] %
data [separator=&, read from file = EMR_VA.csv];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Could you please help me?

The csv file has 3 columns, delimited by `&`, and some values have decimals, separated by comma.

Comment: What does `EMR_VA.csv` look like?

Comment: I am pretty sure, that you have to escape `&` in `col sep = &` and `separator=&`.  Try replacing both instances with `\&`.

Comment: No unfortunately this doesnt help.. from the manual  `/pgfplots/table/col sep=space|tab|comma|semicolon|colon|braces|&|ampersand`

Comment: @Giacomo That's `col sep` not `separator`.

Comment: Do you want a 3D scatter plot, since there are three columns? If not, which two columns do you want? Is there a header line in your `.csv` file? For convenience, a sample file would be nice (just need a few lines). Finally, is using `pgfplots` an option, or do you require the `datavisualization` library?

Comment: No I just need to plot 2 series on the same graph. I solved it using `pgfplots`.

Comment: I know this is an old one, however, `tikz-datavisualization` needs the provided data with a dot/point as the decimal separator between the integer and the fractional part of the numbers. It does not work with a comma!